# 店を休んで、電車で薬屋へ行きました

Tags: meaning

> 店を休んで、電車で薬屋へ行きました

Does this sentence mean that: the person is absent/resting from the store (that he may work at), and had caught the train to go to the pharmacy?

This is from the text book I am trying to work through.

I'd say it's the connection of this part that I'm unsure about: 店を休んで

Comment: `店を休んで, 電車で薬屋へ行きました Does this sentence mean that: the person is absent/resting from the store (that he may work at), and had caught the train to go to the pharmacy?` -- Yes, it can mean that too...

Answer (score 0):

G'day to you too.

If you were referring to work, school, etc., ～を休む would simply mean to 'take time off from ～'. As you normally wouldn't actually close the entire school or workplace.

In this instance, however, the use of 店 is telling. By choosing to not say 'work', rather 'the store' it likely means that they will be 'closing the store temporarily'.

Some examples:

> 「今日は店は休みのようだ。」It appears that the store is closed today.
>
> 「私のお店は年中無休です。」My shop is open (without fixed closures) year round.
>
> A fixed closure day is 定休日 and an irregular closure day would be 休店日 (休業日）.

In other words, 'closing' a shop uses the word 休む by default.